# calculation of balance after each transaction and opening bal

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Database table namely

```
Cust_Table(CustID, CustName, custAddrs, CustMob, CustOpBal)
```

And

```
Trans_Table(TransId, CustID, TransAmt, TransType(bool dr/cr), Msg, TansDate)
```

Now I need the SQL Query for getting Statement like (Bank Passbook) for a particular
Customer ID?

```
Date     Message    Dt_Amount   Cr_Amount   Balance
```

Iam using the following query

```
SELECT t1.Trans_Date, t1.Trans_Msg,
(CASE WHEN t1.Trans_Type=1 THEN 'Cr' ELSE 'Dr' END) as Trans_Type,
t1.Trans_Amount,
SUM(t2.Trans_Amount*case when t2.trans_type = '1' then 1 else -1 end) as Balance
FROM [LNLCredit].[dbo].[Trans_Table] t1
INNER JOIN [LNLCredit].[dbo].[Trans_Table] t2 
ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id AND t1.trans_id >= t2.Trans_ID
WHERE t1.Cust_ID=2
GROUP BY t1.cust_id,t1.trans_id,t1.trans_type,t1.Trans_Amount,t1.Trans_Date,t1.Trans_Msg;
```

Its working fine.

But I also want to add Opening Balance (from Cust_Table) to the above solution.

Please Help??????

Comment: Just join to `Cust_Table`, add any field from there and don't forget include it into `Group By` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT t1.Trans_Date, t1.Trans_Msg,
(CASE WHEN t1.Trans_Type=1 THEN 'Cr' ELSE 'Dr' END) as Trans_Type,
t1.Trans_Amount,
SUM(t2.Trans_Amount*case when t2.trans_type = '1' then 1 else -1 end) as Balance,
c.CustOpBal
FROM [LNLCredit].[dbo].[Trans_Table] t1
INNER JOIN [LNLCredit].[dbo].[Trans_Table] t2 
         ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id AND t1.trans_id >= t2.Trans_ID
INNER JOIN Cust_Table C on C.cust_id = t1.cust_id
WHERE t1.Cust_ID=2
GROUP BY t1.cust_id,t1.trans_id,t1.trans_type,t1.Trans_Amount,
         t1.Trans_Date,t1.Trans_Msg,C.CustOpBal;
```

You need to add an extra `INNER JOIN` and add openingBalance column to `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`

Comment: Its ok, But I need to update the opening balance in Transaction Balance.